# How to notify SIP client when there is an incoming call on another phone

Tags: sip

is it possible to notify a SIP client when there is an incoming call on another phone?
I know that there are the SUBSCRIBE and NOTIFY commands but I have found no event package for signaling incoming calls.

Background: for a SIP-capable telephony system, I would like to provide an application that displays information about the caller (e.g. name, address, contracts, etc.) when the phone rings. The phones are external to the PC; they are not soft-phones.

-Frank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [dialog event package (RFC4235)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4235) is what you're after. The key realisation is that dialog's get established when the first non-100 response is received on an INVITE transaction.

A dialog is in the early state until the INVITE is answered with a final response but that doesn't matter as the dialog event package is designed to send notifications for early dialogs just the same as for answered dialogs.

Finding servers or providers that supprt the dialog event package is another matter. The best softphone that I have come across for SIP events is the [Bria](http://www.counterpath.com/bria.html), as far as servers go [sip2sip](http://sip2sip.info) and my own [sipsorcery](http://www.sipsorcery.com) have some level of support for the dialog event package although I must admit I have left out early dialog notifications.

Comment: The Dialog Event Package for SIP can contains caller information but does not have to. The section https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4235#section-3.6 explained that there must be authentication and authorization to get sensitive data like caller information. It depends to User Agent (UA) that has implemented the authentication.