# [android][lock_screen] Unlock standby screen during incoming sip call

Tags: android, unlock

I am writing a `sip` based calling application. When there is an incoming call the corresponding activity for it is fired and is getting displayed below the lock screen. But the user doesn't get to know about the call...the lock screen comes up for a while and screen turns off..even when the call is still ringing...the ringtone is active for the entire duration but screen doesn't show the incoming call UI. I need to find a way to display the appropriate UI and keep screen on for the whole duration of incoming call...

For the part of keeping the screen on for the whole duration of incoming call I am using wakelocks...but I am not able to get rid of the lock screen...

I researched and found that can use `KeygaurdManager` or `WindowManager.LayoutParams` with appropriate flags like `FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON`, `FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGAURD`, `FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED` and `FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON` to unlock the phone...however these don't work in my case...I read in one of the following links that one cannot unlock the phone when the phone is password/pattern locked...is this the issue why i am unable to display the UI i want? How does it work for incoming phone calls? Please suggest me some solutions

The links that i referred to are

[How can I unlock the screen programmatically in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959012/how-can-i-unlock-the-screen-programmatically-in-android)

[Unlock the Android Lockscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6058990/unlock-the-android-lockscreen)

[How do I prevent an Android device from going to sleep programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3723634/how-can-i-prevent-an-android-phone-from-going-to-sleep-programmatically)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7006894/how-to-unlack-the-screen-and-power-on-when-my-application-is-in-background-when

[Force Screen On](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2131948/force-screen-on)

[unlock screen while in call android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383204/unlock-screen-while-in-call-android)

[Android: Turn screen ON and notify user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693773/android-turn-screen-on-and-notify-user)

[How to launch an activity when lock screen is enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161699/how-to-launch-an-activity-when-lock-screen-is-enabled)

[Android activity over default lock screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629179/android-activity-over-default-lock-screen)

[Android Create An Activity That Float Over Lockscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8185572/android-create-an-activity-that-float-over-lockscreen)

[Unlock Android phone programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9004720/unlock-android-phone-programmatically)

[How to display Activity when the screen is locked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793221/how-my-app-can-unlock-screen-programatically)

[How to unlock the device when my activity will be launched programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531674/how-to-unlock-the-device-when-my-activity-will-be-launched-programmatically)

[Android: How to turn screen on and off programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561320/android-how-to-turn-screen-on-and-off-programmatically)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10590918/how-to-display-dialog-when-user-get-incoming-call-on-default-call-screen-in-andr

[How to show incoming call notification in android application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771648/how-to-show-incoming-call-notification-in-android-application)

[How to display Activity when the screen is locked?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793221/how-my-app-can-unlock-screen-programatically)

[How to dismiss lock screen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5390365/how-to-dismiss-lock-screen)

[problem with KeyGuardManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3908337/problem-with-keyguardmanager)

[How unlock and lock screen programatically in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7648347/how-unlock-and-lock-screen-programtically-in-android)

[How to unlock the device when my activity will be launched programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8531674/how-to-unlock-the-device-when-my-activity-will-be-launched-programmatically)

[Get the Sip Incoming call id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696817/get-the-sip-incoming-call-id)

[How to notify SIP client when there is an incoming call on another phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2883588/how-to-notify-sip-client-when-there-is-an-incoming-call-on-another-phone)

[Can an activity receive an unordered broadcast(incoming call) intent before system's default receiver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9869314/can-an-activity-receive-an-unordered-broadcastincoming-call-intent-before-syst)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you get the solution?if your issue was resolved please tell me how to do it is very helpful to me.

Comment: did u find the solution for this ?

Answer (score 1):

For me following code works well.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate() {
    KeyguardManager km = (KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    keyguard = km.newKeyguardLock("MyApp");
}
//when we need to unlock screen
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    keyguard.disableKeyguard();
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    keyguard.enableKeyguard();
}
```

Remember to add permission as well

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD" />`

Comment: Hi, The keygaurd helps in dealing with the keys...I want to deal with the unlock screen. Please suggest some answer for dealing with the standby screen

Answer (score 0):

FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED works for me on most phones.  The activity must be non-transparent (not a dialog).  You might also want FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON and FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON

However, it isn't currently working for me on a Galaxy Note running 4.0.3.  Not yet sure why...